# What happens to nginx when I use named pipes as log file and remove and recreate the pipe?

Tags: nginx, named-pipes, logging

I'm using named pipes as the log file for the access_log of my nginx, I want to know what happens internally in nginx when I delete and recreate the pipe. What I note is that nginx keep working but stop logging.

Even if i don't create again the pipe nginx didn't try to create a regular file for logging.

I don't want to lose my logs, but apparently the only option is to restart nginx, can I enforce nginx to check again for the log file?

The error log only says this, even if the pipe doesn't exists or the pipe is recreated:

```
2012/02/27 22:45:13 [alert] 24537#0: *1097 write() to "/tmp/access.log.fifo" failed (32: Broken pipe) while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "localhost:8002"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFIAK, you need to send nginx a USR1 signal to instruct it to reopen the log files. Basically nginx will keep trying to write to the file-descriptor for the old files (that's why you are seeing the Broken Pipe error). More info here:

http://wiki.nginx.org/LogRotation  (also click through the other links at the bottom of that page).

hth